# EXCEL: Get a subtable based on columns filtered by inputs

Tags: input

I have the following excel table with each month sales by users (is just an example):

| User | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3 | Month 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 42 | 13 | 02 | 21 |
| Mark | 15 | 11 | 07 | 84 |

I want to get how many sales did John make between month 2 and 4 (inclusive) based on inputs.

I have two cells one with "from month" and "to month" so I want to type there 2 and 4 and calculate it.

I'm basically looking for something that lets me get a table based on another table and get that table limited by starting and end column and then do the sum over that new table.

Something like SUBTABLE(WHOLEDOCUMENT,FROM+1,TO+1) so if I choose 2 and 4 as from and to months it will get me a subtable that only contains the 3rd and 5th columns of the document.

I'm probably overcomplicating this and there is an easier way, I just want to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: mock-up the results table as well as any intermediate tables.

Answer (score -1):

So basically what I wanted to do was to have Month 1 to Month 4 dynamically populated in two dropdowns to choose the from and to so I could filter by user and by a period of months.

What I ended up doing was to create a column after the last month that had the sum of the row depending on the value of the dropdowns and then another cell got the result of that new cell based on the user.

I wanted to do it all at once but this way was easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).